# How to create a SharePoint content type with 'Document' as the parent

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to use SharePoint REST to create a content type. I intended the content type to use the 'Document' as its parent (0x0101). But every time I tried the code, it creates a content type with 'Item' as its parent(0x01).

Here is the complete code:

```
// URL variable
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl

// Options variable
var options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "accept":  "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": _spPageContextInfo.formDigestValue
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: {
        type: "SP.ContentType"
    },
    Id: {
        __metadata: {
            type: "SP.ContentTypeId"
        },
        StringValue: '0x01010040C0C59A4C644983AE2877D595FC9D38'
    },
    Name: 'My New Document',
    Description: 'My New Document',
    Group: 'My New Document'
        })
}

// Run fetch on the browser console.
fetch(                     
  url + "/_api/web/contenttypes",                     
  options              
).then( 
  res => res.json().then(json => console.dir(json)) 
)
```

Can anyone show me what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in below to links:

1. [Create content type using REST](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8b4a0607-8fdb-4b42-9ea4-0a333a23916e/create-contenttype-using-rest-need-help)
2. [Content type id ignored when using sp.web.contenttypes.add](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/457)

Content types are very broken in REST API and one sould not use REST to do anything with content types.

So, I will suggest you to use the JSOM to create a content type where you can easily mention the Parent content type using `set_parentContentType()`.

**Code for reference**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contentTypeCollection;

    function createContentType() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();
            this.contentTypeCollection = web.get_contentTypes();
            this.contentType = contentTypeCollection.getById("0x0101");

            var newContentType = new SP.ContentTypeCreationInformation();
            newContentType.set_name('My Custom Content Type');
            newContentType.set_description('My custom content type');
            newContentType.set_parentContentType(contentType);
            this.contentTypeCollection.add(newContentType);

            clientContext.load(this.contentTypeCollection);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("Content Type created successfully")
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: How to create Content Type using JavaScript object model?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36812.sharepoint-online-how-to-create-content-type-using-javascript-object-model.aspx)

**Similar Issue**: [How to create site content type with id using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529315/how-to-create-site-content-type-with-id-using-rest-api).

Comment: Thank you Ganesh