# How to create a new content type in SharePoint using MS Graph / REST?

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, java

I tried to add a new content type to list using **MS Graph Explorer**:

Request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/contenttypes
```

with body:

```
{
  "description": "MyCustomContentType's description",
  "group": "List Content Types",
  "hidden": false,
  "id": "0x010300B8123BA6FE3D6045BF4F6DF992B6ABE7",
  "name": "MyCustomContentType",
  "parentId": "0x0103",
  "readOnly": false,
  "sealed": false
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified site content type was not found",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1ac12fed-eaf3-4d03-a3c4-b44ddacada72",
            "date": "2020-05-16T17:12:11"
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried this with **Graph API sdk** in Java code:

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .buildClient();

ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
contentType.name = "MyCustomContentType";
contentType.description = "MyCustomContentType's description";
contentType.group = "List Content Types";
contentType.hidden = false;
contentType.parentId = "0x0103";
contentType.id = "0x010300B8123BA6FE3D6045BF4F6DF992B6ABE7";
contentType.readOnly = false;
contentType.sealed = false;

contentType = graphClient.sites(siteId)
        .lists(listId)
        .contentTypes()
        .buildRequest()
        .post(contentType);
```

the result is the same...

Also I tried to add content type to list using **REST API** but faced with another problem: content type is created but it ignores passed id and always inherited from **Item** content type. The same problem described here: [How to create a SharePoint content type with 'Document' as the parent](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276484/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-content-type-with-document-as-the-parent). It seems like a bug of REST API.

Is it possible to create a content type in SharePoint using MS Graph or REST API? Maybe there are other ways to create it using Java?

Thanks!